# copy files without rows beginning on specific words

Tags: shell, file-io, delete-row

I am beginner in shell script. Please how can I delete specific rows beginning on word "include" or if row is empty. Empty row can by also first line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed:

```
sed -i.bak '/^[[:blank:]]*$\|include/d' file
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Can you elaborate, how is this not an answer?

Comment: This absolutely dont work for me:-( empty rows still exist in output file

Comment: Those type of comments are absolutely not going to help you. Show you sample input and expected output in your question.

Comment: Thank you good as example, but i dont know how to used it for empty low rows deletion

Comment: check updated answer. If it doesn't work then do as I suggested that is **provide your sample input data and expected output in your question**

Comment: Excellent, this is exacly what i need. THANK YOU

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.